# How to keep samba connection with TOSMBClient Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, smb, libsmbclient

I'm following TOSMBClient library [link:TOSMBClient](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOSMBClient) to share file from pc to my iPhone,This library is working to connect and copy file to my iPhone. But it takes very long time to connect to host and every time when copy file is done samba will disconnect. I want to keep samba connection.

Have anyone have idea or used to work with TOSMBClient library please help or suggest idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the original developer of `TOSMBClient`. :)

The library is a thin Objective-C wrapper around another library called [`libdsm`](https://github.com/videolabs/libdsm). The process of connecting to a host is at libdsm's level, so if your particular connection is slow, there's not a lot that can be done on the `TOSMBClient` level. It might be worth reporting an issue on `libdsm`'s Github repo describing your hardware setup.

The connection dropping after a file copy operation is complete is curious. I can't be sure where that issue might be happening. Again, more information would be required. A complete set of steps to reproduce would be great. If you get the chance, feel free to file another issue on the GitHub!